# What are the steps to create a USB flash drive to upgrade an AMI BIOS?

Tags: bios, uefi

I have a CentOS machine with a two years old [AMI](https://ami.com/en/) UEFI (BIOS).

Upgrading the BIOS is only allowed from a USB flash drive/disk (not directly from the Internet, like on Asus, for instance).

However, I cannot create a USB flash drive that will accept a new BIOS file, that I'm able to use to upgrade the AMI BIOS.

Do you know the steps to create a USB that could be used to upgrade an AMI BIOS?

Comment: Make and specific model of PC?

Answer (score 1):

Often, you just copy the BIOS file to the root of the FAT32-formatted flashdrive, boot into the BIOS, and then press the function key associated with BIOS Update. For example, <kbd>F7</kbd> is a popular choice for BIOS Upgrades with AMI; but confirm that by going into the BIOS, and then look on the bottom of the screen and see if <kbd>F7</kbd> is listed there for BIOS UPDATE.

If it is, power down, then insert the flash drive with the file for the update, and get into the BIOS, then press <kbd>F7</kbd> and choose the BIOS file to use for the update.